# Adb says: "target didn't report max-download-size"

Tags: android, adb, xiaomi

I'm trying to install `TWRP` in a Xiaomi Redmi note 5 but I can.
I have been trying a lot of stuff I have found on the internet but I don't what to do now.

I have my device unlocked and I have USB debugging activated.

I got the following message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot devices

4357e24 fastboot

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash recovery xiaomi.img

target didn't report max-download-size

sending 'recovery' (42452 KB)...

FAILED (command write failed (No error))

finished. total time: 0.016s
```

The `xiaomi.img` is the name of my image of TWRP.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the USB cable or try recovery file it may be corrupted, I tried those methods and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what mode you are in.

fastboot flash will not normally work under bootloader mode (I only saw one exception being LG).

You may want to get into the default Recovery mode, and fiddle with the volume up and power button. It may reveal a menu to launch fastbootd mode.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few things you can try:

1. Restart bootloader
2. Check if device name is correct under: **fastboot devices**
3. Connect/disconnect USB cable
4. Replace with another USB cable try to use USB cable received from manufacturer
5. Re-execute the commands several times, it works

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution about the `max-download-size` error report,
We can check the help commands and get the -S param infomation.

```
fastboot --help
  -S SIZE[K|M|G]             Break into sparse files no larger than SIZE.
```

let us guess the terrible error message about which like `Requested download size is more than the max allowed` means:
One of the files in the zip is bigger than `max-download-size`.

I edit the `flash-all.sh`

```
...
fastboot -S 256M -w update image-taimen-qq3a.200805.001.zip
```